# GWT PushButton image/text alignment

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

I'm trying to create buttons with custom color and image/text on it. To add color and image/text was quite easy, but now i have problems with vertical alignment. "text-alignment: center" helped me with horizontal alignment, but no luck with vertical.

```
<ui:style>
    .gwt-b {
        margin: 50px;
        height: 23px;
        width: 60px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#357ae8);
        border: 1px solid #3079ED;
        outline-color: #3079ED;
        outline-width: 3px;
    }
</ui:style>

<g:HorizontalPanel>
    <g:PushButton ui:field='pushButton' enabled='true' addStyleNames="{style.gwt-b}">
        <g:upFace image="{res.search}">
        </g:upFace>
    </g:PushButton>

    <g:PushButton ui:field='pushButton2' enabled='true' addStyleNames="{style.gwt-b}">
        <g:upFace>
            <b>click me</b>
        </g:upFace>
    </g:PushButton>
<g:HorizontalPanel>
```

Here is what i've got:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
.gwt-b {        
    ...
    line-height: 12px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: it helps in case of text, but not image

Answer (score 0):

IE8+

```
.gwt-b {
    ...
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    ...
}
```